How do I securely allow users to export their private keys?
I am working on a Telegram based trading bot which gives each new user a new wallet, into which they can transfer SOL for further trading.
I am using Keypair.generate() from solana/web3js(Node.js,Typescript) to create new Keypairs for new users.
Now I want to be able to add the feature of users being able to export their private keys from within the bot interface, however I don't see how to do it without storing their private key on my database, which I know is something that should be avoided at all costs due to security issues.
Am I able to store the private key somehow on user's devices like most browser based wallets do? If not, and there's no other option other than to store the secret key in my MongoDB database, what security precautions should I be taking to ensure the safety of the secret key stored in the db?
